# Storing entire GeoJSON document in PostgreSQL/PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geojson

I am trying to insert GeoJSON document in my PostgreSQL, I cannot just simply use the data type Geometry and use the expression ST_GEOMFROMGEOJSON because my geoJSON looks like this, and I need to store it all, what do you suggest?

GeoJSON Document

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::26916" } },

"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "h": -0.400000, "mean": null }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ 337120.0, 4659412.460953020490706 ], [ 337121.0, 4659412.271286088041961 ], [ 337121.32677364279516, 4659412.0 ], [ 337121.581764082075097, 4659411.0 ], [ 337121.0, 4659410.470878113992512 ], [ 337120.0, 4659410.360407529398799 ], [ 337119.0, 4659410.916399526409805 ], [ 337118.937826662964653, 4659411.0 ], [ 337119.0, 4659411.488602316007018 ], [ 337119.127736570662819, 4659412.0 ], [ 337120.0, 4659412.460953020490706 ] ] ] ] } }
]}
```

There are more lines but I've cut it down. I have tried inserting it as text only, but then when I wanted to export the result it offered me CSV, XHTML,tabbed or XML and they all start putting  random " marks. so I am guessing Text data type is not the way. I am sure someone out there tried inserting complete GeoJSON not only the geometry part.

bytea the .geojson file?

Comment: Do you want to store the geometry as a PostGIS geometry type, or just as text?

Comment: as either as long as I can retrieve it the same way I've put it in

Comment: @JadFreyha provide more input or pick an answer?

Answer (score 4):

You can't store this as GeoJSON, because there is no GeoJSON type. For reference, [PostgreSQL native types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype.html), and then [PostGIS provides a half dozen more](http://postgis.net/docs/reference.html#PostGIS_Types). If you actually need to store the entire GeoJSON, I would use a `jsonb` type. (sample jacked from http://geojson.org/)

```
CREATE TABLE foo AS SELECT $$
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [125.6, 10.1]
    },
    "properties": {
      "name": "Dinagat Islands"
    }
  }
$$::jsonb AS geojson;
```

[`ST_GeomFromGeoJSON`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromGeoJSON.html) doesn't do what you want. It only takes the `geometry` object in the GeoJSON document: you say you have to store the entire thing. From there you can use the normal [Postgres JSON functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) to get to the `geometry` object, and even call `ST_GeomFromGeoJSON` on that object (rather than the whole document).

```
SELECT ST_AsEWKT(
  ST_GeomFromGeoJSON((geojson->'geometry')::text)
) FROM foo;
```

**Note** we do a little more work here casting the object to text, because `ST_GeomFromGeoJSON` doesn't currently read `jsonb` (the *type* that the `->` operator returns)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are wanting to convert GeoJSON data to PostGIS data?  (not "store GeoJSON in PostGIS" - which would just store GeoJSON as plain text in a PostGIS database)

One way would be to use the `ogr2ogr` utility from GDAL/OGR.  Eg,

```
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"dbname=aDBName user=postgres" "someJSONData.json"
```